# Functional Dependency query

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Say I have a relation called `PAPER = {ID, Title, Description, No.Students, Quarter}`.

If I say `ID -> Title` and `{Title, Quarter} -> No.Students`. Is there an axiom that permits me to say `{ID, Quarter} -> No.Students`?

Because if id determines title, can't I just replace title with id in the second functional dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the additional rules derived from Armstrong's axioms is the rule of pseudo-transitivity. It states that

```
If A->B and BC->D then AC->D.
```

Substituting your terms . . .

```
If ID->Title and {Title, Quarter}->No.Students, then {ID, Quarter}->No.Students
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would I be able to say Title -> Id?

Comment: Not based on the functional dependencies in your question.